# Getting syntax error when running a simple perform

Tags: database, postgresql

Why am I getting a syntax error on this simple `perform` call

```
create or replace function foo ()
returns void
as $$
begin
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

perform * from foo ();
```

I tested it online at [ExtendsClass](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html)

[image]

Comment: Replace `perform * from foo ();` with `select * from foo ();`.

Answer (score 1):

`PERFORM` is a PL/pgSQL statement, not a SQL one. This means it can only be used between the BEGIN and END of a function definition. See below, where I call bar() from foo() using PERFORM.

```sql
create or replace function bar ()
returns void
as $$
begin
RAISE NOTICE 'bar() ran';
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

create or replace function foo ()
returns void
as $$
begin
perform bar();
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

The SQL fiddle site you've linked doesn't show stderr, but if you paste the above into psql and then `select * from foo();`, you'll see that `bar()` ran.

```
testdb=# select * from foo();
NOTICE:  bar() ran
 foo 
-----
 
(1 row)
```

Comment: If I run it using `select` I get this error: `query has no destination for result data...If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead`. The only way is to wrap it in another function?

Comment: No. If you call in in SQL, use `SELECT`. If you call it in PL/pgSQL, use `SELECT ... INTO` or `PERFORM`.